# Script to monitor a certain amount of files in a directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm breaking my head with a simple script and I need help.

I have the following scenario:

I have a directory to monitor where the script will run until the number of files reaches the expected number (exit 0)
or the expiration time arrives (exit 1)

---

Rules:

1. Number of files hit, exit 0
2. Time limit hit even without the amount of files reached, exit 0

Usage: ./filemonitor.sh  <file_mask> <file_amount> <expire_time>

Eg   : ./filemonitor.sh /home/abc/ dl*.txt 5 14

I don't know if I made myself clear but what am I doing wrong?

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
now=$(date +"%H")

# User input
files_path=$1
files_msk=$2
files_qtde=$3
files_lmttime=$4

check() {

    while :; do

        file_count=$(find $files_path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "$files_msk" | wc -l)

        if [ $file_count -lt $files_qtde ]; then

            if [ $now -ge $files_lmttime ]; then

                echo 'Time is over!'
                exit 1

            elif [ $now -lt $files_lmttime ]; then

                echo 'On time, process running'
                echo 'Wait 5 secs'
                sleep 5

            fi

        elif [ $file_count -eq $files_qtde ]; then

            echo "file count="$file_count "file expected="$files_qtde
            echo 'Files OK'
            exit 0

        fi

    done
}

check
```

Comment: `min/max depth 1` is a sign that `find` is not needed.

Comment: Find command thas ok, but if statment was something wrong that I dont see

Comment: How do you ensure dl\*.txt does never expand to more than one argument? btw in your usage the first argument is missing

Comment: This argument will be passed as a parameter in the command to run the script.

The problem is the if then else mechanic is not working.

In summary, I have a directory to monitor that needs to have X files up to an expiration time.



Example:
  The /home/abc directory must contain 5 files by 2pm, if the 5 files with the name dl*.txt do not arrive, the script stops with exit 1.



The command for this would be:
`./filemonitor.sh /home/abc/ dl*.txt 5 14`(24h time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks for all.

```
# Check user to run
if [[ $USER != "abc" ]]; then
    echo "Abc user needed to run!"
    exit 1
fi

# Variables
now=$(date +"%H")
pause_time=2
log_path='/home/abc/logs/'
log_time=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
log_file=$log_path$(date +"%Y%m%d")"_filemonitor.log"

# User input
files_path=$1
files_msk=$2
files_qtde=$3
files_lmttime=$4

# Check if log path exist
if [ ! -d $log_path ]; then
    echo 'Log directory does not exist. Creating...'
    mkdir -p $log_path
fi

# Check if log file exist
if [ ! -f $log_file ]; then
    echo 'Log file does not exist. Creating...'
    touch $log_file
fi

check() {

    while :; do
        # Count how many files are in the directory
        file_count=$(ls -1 $files_path | wc -l)

        # Checks if the number of files in the directory is less than the expected amount.
        if [ $file_count -lt $files_qtde ]; then

            # Checks if the current time is less than the expiration time passed by the user
            if [ $now -gt $files_lmttime ]; then
                echo -e $log_time "Waiting for files. Wait $pause_time secs" >>$log_file
                sleep $pause_time
            else
                # Cancels the process due to time expired
                echo -e $log_time 'Time is over!' >>$log_file
                echo -e $log_time "Error" >>$log_file
                exit 1
            fi
        # Checks if the number of files equals the expected number
        elif [ $file_count -eq $files_qtde ]; then
            echo -e $log_time "Files OK" >>$log_file
            echo -e $log_time "Process OK" >>$log_file
            exit 0
        # Checks if the number of files is greater than the expected number
        elif [ $file_count -gt $files_qtde ]; then

            # Checks if the current time is less than the expiration time passed by the user
            if [ $now -gt $files_lmttime ]; then
                echo -e $log_time "Number of files larger than expected." >>$log_file
                echo -e $log_time "[$files_path] contains = "$file_count "files" >>$log_file
                echo -e $log_time "Error" >>$log_file
                exit 1
            else
                # Cancels the process due to time expired
                echo -e $log_time 'Time is over!' >>$log_file
                echo -e $log_time "Error" >>$log_file
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
    done
}

check
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When reading your answer like this, it's hard to know exactly what the solution was without reading the whole code block, rendering your answer less valuable than it could be. Don't hesitate to add a small explanation of what the actual solution is before the code block!